# How can I get OnMouseEnter to trigger on a 3D Text in Unity3D?

Tags: unity

I've just started to learn Unity3D.

I want to create a simple 3D menu with just two 3D Text instances.
I've created and named them, then dropped this script:

```
function Awake(){
    print("MenuItem "+gameObject.name+" init!");
}
function OnMouseEnter(){
    print("OnMouseEnter " + gameObject.name);
}
function OnMouseDown(){
    print("OnMouseDown " + gameObject.name);
}
```

I only see the init/awake message printed in the console.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I forgot to add the BoxCollider(Physics>Box Collider) to my object, so no events were triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure that everything else is set up correctly.

In a different script that's running somewhere, put in this bit of code (C#, and from memory so it may not be 100% accurate):

```
RaycastHit hitInfo;
if( Physics.Raycast( Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( Input.mousePosition ), out hitInfo ) )
{
    Debug.Log( "mouse is over object " + hitInfo.collider.name );
}
```

If that doesn't work then you probably don't have your colliders set up correctly.  If it does print out something then you have something else messed up.

Comment: ScreenPointToRay look handy, thanks! what dows the out keyword do ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.80).aspx